# Left and right side on a webpage are not displaying correctly

Tags: css

I am having a problem the heading of the left side is displaying on the right and the image of the left is displaying on the right, some of the text is displaying correctly but not all of it. I am a novice working for a non profit and it is taking a long time to get this right. Can someone help?

```
html, body {
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Lato;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;/* IE6 hack */        /*top, right, bottom, left */
    min-height: 1% !important;
    padding: 0;
}
#main{
    overflow: auto;
    padding:0; margin:0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#left {
    width: 43%;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 2em;
    display: inline;
    }

#right {
    width: 43%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0; margin:0;
    }
```

Comment: Without the HTML, you've only given us half the story. Please post that so we can see.

Comment: Its OK I have fixed it now, thanks